How to generate multiple logs with n_retry autosys option
When i used n_retry option in autosys job, it is creating only one log for multiple runs. When it failed for the first time, n_retrys restarting the job for 3 times but it generates only one log. Previous logs are overwritten. I used timestamp as well.Can anyone help me with solution to create multiple logs for multiple runs by n_retry option.
N_retrys: 3
I actually need log for every restart made by n_retrys option when the job is failed.
